# Is there a way to have a global diff before doing a checkin in TFS

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2013

With Visual Studio and TFS, is there a way to have a diff showing in a single page changes for each file before doing a checkin ? Instead of having to do diff of each file one after the other.

Similar to the UI of GitHub for Windows when doing a commit:

- file1

  - diff
- file2

  - diff
- ...

Thanks,

Edit: as mentioned by Jehan33 the view I'm looking for looks like this (it's available on the web portal AFTER a commit):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This view is available after the check-in for the change sets where it will display all the file differences for a changeset in single page in web portal. Its not possible to do the same before the check-in.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your are using Team Foundation Version Control. If you right click on the folder where you have pending changes and click Compare. Select the options

"Show Items that exists only in source path", "Show Items that exists only in target path" and "Show items that are different", you will get the desired view.

Comment: I can in this view to a diff for each file, but it does not show a global diff ? or am I missing something ?

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were after a view where all changed files are viewed. Now that the question is modified, I don't think this view will work.

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing I've found was **[Diff All Files](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d8d61cc9-6660-41af-b8d0-0f8403b4b39c)**.

You can choose to combine all changed files into one and compare. Sadly there is no 'lines of context', however the code is [open source](https://diffallfilesvisualstudioextension.codeplex.com/) and you can choose an external diff tool which may achieve this.

[image: Diff All Files extension in Team Explorer pane]